# App Engine UserService calls in servlet throw thread exception - Eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I have a basic Google App Engine java project in Eclipse that uses GWT. I followed the instructions to set up the app engine SDK and latest GWT in Eclipse and set the environment variables path in Windows to point to the SDK root folder.

When a login servlet is called by clicking the login link on the start page (as defined in the web.xml file) the call is routed to my HttpServlet handler class as expected. So that works fine. In the code I create the UserService via the factory method, but then **any call such as isUserLoggedIn() or createLoginURL() results in an exception**. I'm hoping the problem is obvious but I've spent hours trying to figure out what is causing this problem with no luck :(

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    if (userService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
```

Here is the console output for when the call to isUserLoggedIn() happens:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Operation not allowed in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
at com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceImpl.getCurrentEnvironmentOrThrow(UserServiceImpl.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceImpl.isUserLoggedIn(UserServiceImpl.java:96)
```

Does this look familiar to anyone using this type of development environment? I'm hoping it is a simple setting in the project or xml config files or something I'm missing. I've successfully run similar code several years ago but just getting back to working with GAE so maybe something important has changed with servlets or project setup. Thanks so much for any help and tips.

Comment: Could you add some more details about how you're launching your webapp? Are you using the [Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/)?  Or the older (and recently deprecated) [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/)?

Comment: Sorry I missed your follow up question. I installed the Cloud Tools for Eclipse, though I admit the install/config progress to get the app engine tools plus GWT and Objectify was a bit confusing. Is there a way to tell?  It's possible something is not right. 
When I Debug I choose the 'GWT Development Mode with Jetty" option.

Answer (score 1):

To make use of App Engine APIs, you must run/debug your apps locally using the *Development App Server*.  Within Eclipse, right-click on the project and select *Run As > App Engine* or *Debug As > App Engine*.  See [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/running-and-debugging) for a bit more detail.

To enable GWT, you'll need to configure the GWT SDM Builder by right-clicking on the project and selecting *Configure > Enable GWT SDM builder*.

Comment: Thanks. Your advice got me a lot further. I was using Debug As GWT Development Mode with Jetty. After numerous tries I finally got it to load App Engine debug after enabling GWT SDM builder. Yes! There are so many debug as options including with/without Jetty, Legacy, App Engine. It can be confusing because most online documentation describes the plug-in without being aware of the new Cloud Tools for Eclipse. I never found reference to the GWT SDM builder so thanks for that! I don't understand why all these debug configs are created by default. I guess I can delete the old style ones?

Comment: However I'm still running into issues with my Norton Firewall on Windows. I have to figure out a way to allow it to let through all traffic to the local and Google servers. 
Also seeing 2 servers listed in the launch box. One to localhost:8080 and the other to 127.0.0.1:9876. I'll do some more configuration tweaks and tests and follow up here after. It is half working now which is much better than before.

Comment: I had the debugger working on Friday and now on Monday with nothing changed I cannot get the localhost server to respond. I click Debug->App Engine then when I open localhost:8080 I get HTTP 503 error and service unavailable. Then when I try to launch again I keep getting the port already in use error. So I cannot figure out what is causing this. I've checked all the Project Properties and Debug Configurations and currently stuck. Migrating from the Google Eclipse Plugin to the Google Cloud Tools is not an easy task and documentation is very light.

Comment: I hit a similar situation.  Restarting Eclipse fixed it — unfortunately in my case, as I was trying to reproduce it :-(

Comment: BTW: if you have any suggestions for improvements to docs, please [file issues on the GitHub project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/new).  Or give the page a 1-star review: that will prompt for feedback.